# Обнуление переменной после неудачного ввода

Tags: c++

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int value;
    while (cin >> value)
    {
        cout << value << endl;
    }

    cout << "Last correct value: " << value << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Почему после цикла `cout` выводит `0`, а не последнее прочитанное значение?

Comment: Ну так последнее и есть 0, иначе у вас бы цикл while не завершился.

Comment: Вообще-то нет! Ноль есть допустимое значение. Цикл завершится когда cin не сможет прочитать значение (например будут буквы вместо чисел).

Comment: Ок. Ох уж эта перегрузка операторов

Comment: @БьярнеСтрауструп, привет! `while` завершается, когда условие ложно. В `C++` 0 "превращается" в false, поэтому цикл заканчивает работу.

Comment: что это за бред? зачем в while писать cin? как это работает я то знаю, но ЗАЧЕМ ТЕБЕ ЭТО НАДО?

Comment: cin >> value возвращает cin. А вопрос был почему value становится 0, даже если последнее введенное значение было не ноль.

Comment: @Oskar Sharipov, @Alexey Ten: перестаньте нести бред, пожалуйста. В данном цикле "условием" является сам поток `cin`, а не переменная `value`. От значения `value` условие цикла никак не зависит. Поэтому никакое "0 превращается в false" здесь ни при чем.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ну так начиная с C++11 вот что пишут [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt):

> If extraction fails, **zero is written** to value and failbit is set.